# How to validate ajax javascript function to check current element id in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to validate if a string is this or that in javascript, when a receive.js.erb is called upon. In my receive.js.erb file I have;

```
$("#story_new<%= @story.id %>").fadeOut();
```

however, now I'm also going to have a different element come into play which should be like this in the receive.js.erb

```
$("#story_new<%= @story.id %>").fadeOut();
$("#story_save<%= @story.id %>").fadeOut();
```

However, only one will be available at the time of the ajax call. I thought maybe an `if` statement would work, but no idea where to start with it. Something along the lines;

```
var story_new = "#story_new<%= @story.id %>";
var story_save = "#story_save<%= @story.id %>";

if ........ story_new
  $("#story_new<%= @story.id %>").fadeOut();
elseif ......... story_save
  $("#story_save<%= @story.id %>").fadeOut();
end
```

maybe even in a nicer format, I'm no good at java or ajax ;)

Answer (score 0):

It has no sense, as js won't fail, if selector finds no elements. But if still want to check elements existence, you can do it by the following code:

```
var story_new = $("#story_new<%= @story.id %>");
var story_save = $("#story_save<%= @story.id %>");

if (story_new.length)
  story_new.fadeOut();
else if (story_save.length)
  story_save.fadeOut();
```